# Cannot add assembly in VS 2022 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I did a clean install of Windows 11 then installed Visual studio 2022 for .NET desktop environment (C@, Visual Basic, F# with NET and NET Framework). Then I created a project of type windows forms app (.net windows forms (winforms) app) with C# filter. I loaded code from an existing project from VS 2019.
It was
public Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dbConn;
but I changed to
public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dbConn;

I get this error
CS1069  The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

I found under menu \project\add reference the browse option. I tried to add reference to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089 but it was invalid.  The csproj file has net6.0-windows. Can I make connections to sqlServer db using this framework? How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/

Comment: Please use the formatting options to make your text more readable (code, quote, paragraph etc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are dependencies but no references in solution explorer, right click on project node brings up csproj file which has net6.0-windows In the top level menu under project tab is add reference. Right click on project node has add\project references in the drop down menu. Has projects, shared projects, COM, Browse. I used Browse and tried to add a reference to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089 but it was invalid .net 6.0 doesn't have System.Data.SqlClient. it is in .net platform extensions 6. Downloaded and ran MS compatability pack. Then ran nuget package manager and installed System.Data.SqlClient. Now it compiles with 0 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this too. Apparently SqlClient is no longer added to new projects

To fix, right click your project file name and select "Manage Nuget Packages".
Type in "System.Data.SqlClient" in the search box (under the Browse tab) highlight it and click Install button.

All will be well.